# Why the content printed using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup are different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib2

```
url = "http://weibo.com"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup.prettify()
```

The two `print` are different, for example, the code printed by soup.prettify() lacks weibo contents which are exactly what I need. So how can I print the same thing with BeautifulSoup? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *lacks weibo contents*? Using requests both give me the source as is

Comment: @PadraicCunningham like I can see someone's tweet(weibo) when I print html, but can't find it in the second case, since their code are basically different.